# Extract domain from url (including the hard ones)

Tags: php, dns, subdomain

I'm trying to write (or just find an existing) PHP method that can take a link and extract the url. The trick is, it needs to hold under the weight of strange looking domains like:

```
www.champa.kku.ac.th
```

Looking at this one myself with human eyes, I still guessed it incorrectly: thought the domain would be `kku.ac.th` but that gives a dns error when visiting.

So anyone knows of a good way to reliably extract the domain from url:

```
http://site.com/hello.php
http://site.com.uk/hello.php
http://subdomain.site.com/hello.php
http://subdomain.site.com.uk/hello.php
http://www.champa.kku.ac.th/hello.php // and even the one I couldn't tell
```

Comment: whois says kku.ac.th is the domain. I guess they haven't set up the correct DNS record requested for web browsers (as opposed to MX etc).

Comment: I think A record was the term I was looking for!

Comment: pass an environment variable through your web server (such as apache/nginx/iis) to keep track of just like $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. i use $_SERVER['HOST_ROOT'] to store the site base. then you can just check the END of parse_url($url)['host'] with strpos for HOST_ROOT and lob the rest into $subdomains = explode('.', $theRest);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP has the [parse_url()](http://de.php.net/parse_url) function that will help you do the basic splitting into protocol, host, port, and so on.

As to extracting the "right" domain in uncertain cases, this is extremely hard to tell because sometimes, "two-part TLDs" are a measure by the TLD authority (e.g. in the UK) and sometimes are private enterprises (e.g. `.uk.com`).  I think you won't get around maintaining lists of top level domains that have two parts like

- .co.uk
- .ac.uk
- .ac.th

those endings would be treated like TLDs (*Top* level domains), swallowing the second part.

This is the only way of reliably telling apart "two-part TLDs" like `.co.uk` - where `server1.ibm.co.uk` (where the two-part `.co.uk` needs to be removed to determine the domain itself) from regular sub-domains like `server1.ibm.com` (where `.com` needs to be removed).

A good starting point to get a list of many important "two-part TLDs" is the domain search at speednames.com (select "all" in countries). A more complete list can be found as [part of the Ruby domainatrix library](https://github.com/pauldix/domainatrix/blob/master/lib/effective_tld_names.dat).

Comment: I was thinking the same thing regarding "I think you won't get around maintaining lists of top level domains that have two parts" Is there a list? I tried wikipedia and could find only the normal list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Comment: @karl I don't think there's an official list, because many of those are private enterprises. Check out speednames, they have a lot of "two-part TLDs" in their portfolio. It's a good start I think.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe the **[`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/parse_url)** function could help, here ?

In your case, with those URLs, the following portion of code :

```
echo parse_url('http://site.com/hello.php', PHP_URL_HOST) . '<br />';
echo parse_url('http://site.com.uk/hello.php', PHP_URL_HOST) . '<br />';
echo parse_url('http://subdomain.site.com/hello.php', PHP_URL_HOST) . '<br />';
echo parse_url('http://subdomain.site.com.uk/hello.php', PHP_URL_HOST) . '<br />';
echo parse_url('http://www.champa.kku.ac.th/hello.php', PHP_URL_HOST) . '<br />';
```

Gives this output :

```
site.com
site.com.uk
subdomain.site.com
subdomain.site.com.uk
www.champa.kku.ac.th
```

Comment: Thanks Pascal, that solves some of my problem, thanks a lot, but it's not quite what I was concerned about. Pekka nails it more down, so I'll likely choose his answer for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

With Ruby you can use the Domainatrix library / gem

http://www.pauldix.net/2009/12/parse-domains-from-urls-easily-with-domainatrix.html

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'domainatrix'
s = 'http://www.champa.kku.ac.th/dir1/dir2/file?option1&option2'
url = Domainatrix.parse(s)
url.domain
=> "kku"
```

great tool! :-)