# Extract top domain from string php

Tags: php, string

I need to extract the domain name out of a string which could be anything. Such as:

```
$sitelink="http://www.somewebsite.com/product/3749875/info/overview.html";
```

or

```
$sitelink="http://subdomain.somewebsite.com/blah/blah/whatever.php";
```

In any case, I'm looking to extract the 'somewebsite.com' portion (which could be anything), and discard the rest.

Comment: What have you tried? A simple Google search will return many answers for a popular question.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527231/extract-domain-from-url-including-the-hard-ones

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing Domain From URL In PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276516/parsing-domain-from-url-in-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276516/parsing-domain-from-url-in-php  This page was useful. Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With [parse_url($url)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));
?>

The above example will output:

Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
```

Using thos values

```
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST); //hostname
```

or

```
$url_info = parse_url($url);
echo $url_info['host'];//hostname
```

Comment: I think OP wants only the second-level domain

Comment: Ill leave the OP to figure out how to use the array.

Comment: Ok, this looks promising. How do I use just the host portion of the array to turn the 'host' part into a string and ignore the rest? Thanks

Comment: A link to the manual is the post. but ive added how you access thos values

Comment: This was a breeze to use. I appreciate that! Matches well in my preg_replace_callback where I am parsing image urls to display HTML image tags, and leaving the domain as text under the matched photo (image url). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

here it is

```
<?php

$sitelink="http://www.somewebsite.com/product/3749875/info/overview.html";

$domain_pieces = explode(".", parse_url($sitelink, PHP_URL_HOST));

$l = sizeof($domain_pieces);

$secondleveldomain = $domain_pieces[$l-2] . "." . $domain_pieces[$l-1];

echo $secondleveldomain;
```

note that this is not probably the behavior you are looking for, because, for hosts like

```
stackoverflow.co.uk
```

it will echo "co.uk"

---

see:

http://publicsuffix.org/learn/

http://www.dkim-reputation.org/regdom-libs/

http://www.dkim-reputation.org/regdom-lib-downloads/ <-- downloads here, php included

Comment: Hi thanks for the message. You're right, echoing .co.uk in cases like this wouldn't be helpful. It needs to be able to handle any domains (and strip subdomain) if possible.. Thanks anyway tho

Comment: you can use this table as a reference https://wiki.mozilla.org/TLD_List  to build what you need

Answer (score 4):

2 complexe url

```
$url="https://www.example.co.uk/page/section/younameit";
or
$url="https://example.co.uk/page/section/younameit";
```

To get "www.example.co.uk":

```
$host=parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

To get "example.co.uk" only

```
$parts = explode('www.',$host);
$domain = $parts[1];

// ...or...

$domain = ltrim($host, 'www.')
```

If your url includes "www." or not you get the same end result, i.e. "example.co.uk"

Voilà!

Answer (score 2):

You need package that uses [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/), only in this way you can correctly extract domains with two-, third-level TLDs (co.uk, a.bg, b.bg, etc.) and multilevel subdomains. Regex, parse_url() or string functions will never produce absolutely correct result.

I recomend use [TLD Extract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract). Here example of code:

```
$extract = new LayerShifter\TLDExtract\Extract();

$result = $extract->parse('http://www.somewebsite.com/product/3749875/info/overview.html');
$result->getSubdomain(); // will return (string) 'www'
$result->getHostname(); // will return (string) 'somewebsite'
$result->getSuffix(); // will return (string) 'com'
$result->getRegistrableDomain(); // will return (string) 'somewebsite.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

For a string that could be anything, new approach:

```
function extract_plain_domain($text) {

    $text=trim($text,"/");
    $text=strtolower($text);

    $parts=explode("/",$text);
    if (substr_count($parts[0],"http")) {
        $parts[0]="";
    }
    reset ($parts);while (list ($key, $val) = each ($parts)) {
            if (!empty($val)) { $text=$val; break; }
    }

    $parts=explode(".",$text);
    if (empty($parts[2])) {
        return $parts[0].".".$parts[1];
        } else {
        $num_parts=count($parts);
        return $parts[$num_parts-2].".".$parts[$num_parts-1];
        }

} // end function extract_plain_domain
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Utopia Domains library (https://github.com/utopia-php/domains), it will return the domain TLD and public suffix based on Mozilla public suffix list (https://publicsuffix.org), it can be used as an alternative to the currently archived TLDExtract package.

You can use 'parse_url' function to get the hostname from your URL and than use Utopia Domains parser to get the correct TLD and join it together with the domain name:

```php
<?php

require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use Utopia\Domains\Domain;

$url = 'http://demo.example.co.uk/site';

$domain = new Domain(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)); // demo.example.co.uk

var_dump($domain->get()); // demo.example.co.uk
var_dump($domain->getTLD()); // uk
var_dump($domain->getSuffix()); // co.uk
var_dump($domain->getName()); // example
var_dump($domain->getSub()); // demo
var_dump($domain->isKnown()); // true
var_dump($domain->isICANN()); // true
var_dump($domain->isPrivate()); // false
var_dump($domain->isTest()); // false

var_dump($domain->getName().'.'.$domain->getSuffix()); // example.co.uk
```