# how to compute hostname's root name

Tags: regex, url, hostname, tld, sld

I am looking for a way to extract what I called "hostname root" from a given hostname i.e.

```
f('stackoverflow.com') -> 'stackoverflow.com'
f('www.stackoverflow.com') -> 'stackoverflow.com'
f('www.stackoverflow.co.uk') -> 'stackoverflow.co.uk'
```

My first approach was (of course) RegExp but [SLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain) is an issue because there are a considerable amount of options.

Maybe a SLDs database would be a good approach.

**EDIT**

I am working with node.js and by now I am using the [tldjs module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/tldjs)

Comment: Specific to PHP but related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2527231/187606

Comment: you don't say what platform or language you are using but there are libraries to do this for most of them

Comment: @Pekka웃 My question is different from the one you pointed (but thanks): I'm not working with URLs nor `parse_url` PHP function is able (or aims to) to provide the "hostname root".

Comment: See my answer, the bit after `As to extracting the "right" domain in uncertain cases` - it doesn't provide much more information than David's answer though. There simply is no way without having a list of TLDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the entire SLD/TLD database to do this. There's no other general purpose way, especially because there's in some edge cases third or fourth level domains.